# Sort a parameter value in ascending orders in Prolog

Tags: sorting, prolog, distance

I have a list of facts that have those parameters: Name, Longitude, Latitude. I want to write a predicate that sorts the Latitude only.
Here's part of my facts.

```
pool(roy, -75.702744, 45.4089761).
pool(marth, -75.731638, 45.3803301).
pool(jiggy, -75.7449645, 45.40431589).
pool(yamaha, -75.7114829, 45.3993461).
```

I tried to do something of the following but didn't get lucky:

```
 furthest(Lat-Long):- setof(Lat-Long, pool(_, Long, Lat), [Lat-Long|_]).
```

Any ideas of how I should tackle this?

Comment: *...but I didn't get lucky*. What exactly does that mean? You need to be more specific about the error you see. Looking at your call to `setof/3`, though, you're missing the universal quantifier which is required: `setof(Lat-Long, Name^pool(Name, Long, Lat), [Lat-Long|_])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work?

```
pool(roy, -75.702744, 45.4089761).
pool(marth, -75.731638, 45.3803301).
pool(jiggy, -75.7449645, 45.40431589).
pool(yamaha, -75.7114829, 45.3993461).

my_sort:-
findall(forsort(Lat,Name),pool(Name,Long,Lat),List),
msort(List,Sorted),
write(Sorted).

    ?- my_sort.
[forsort(45.3803301,marth),forsort(45.3993461,yamaha),forsort(45.40431589,jiggy),forsort(45.4089761,roy)]
true.
```

Excerpt of manual below(SWI):

msort sorts List to the standard order of terms

Standard Order of Terms:

6. Compound terms are first checked on their arity, then on their functor name (alphabetically) and
   finally recursively on their arguments, leftmost argument first.